# Function pointer in DLL call - how to handle in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, callback

I'm using a native DLL that is called out of my C# application. One of the DLL-functions is defined like this:

```
int set_line(const int width,fct_line_callback callback)
```

fct_line_callback itself is defined as

```
typedef int (*fct_line_callback)(double power,void *userData);
```

So how can I use this function out of my C#-application? Is there a way to define a C# method to be used as callback-function for this DLL-call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare a delegate type that matches the native function pointer.  It probably should look like this:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate int fct_line_callback(double power, IntPtr userdata);
```

Now you can write the pinvoke declaration:

```
[DllImport("foo.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
extern static int set_line(int width, fct_line_callback callback);
```

---

If the callback can only be made *while* set_line() is executing then calling the native function is simple:

```
public void SetLine(int width) {
    set_line(width, MyCallback);
}
private void MyCallback(double power, IntPtr userdata) {
    // etc...
}
```

However, if the callback can be made *after* set_line() is executed, in other words when the native code stores the function pointer, then you have to make sure that the garbage collector cannot collect the delegate object.  Simplest way to do so is by storing the object in a *static* variable:

```
static class Wrapper {
    private static fct_line_callback callback = MyCallback;
    public static void SetLine(int width) {
        set_line(width, callback);
    }
    private static int MyCallback(double power, IntPtr userdata) {
        // etc...
    }
}
```